# Add logo on navigation bar in top left corner using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, imageview, uinavigationbar

I want to add logo on top left corner in Navigation Bar. I tried in design time but didn't worked for me.

[image: Screenshot for design time]

Below is grab of screenshot that I want.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is code that I tried :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        let imgLogo : UIImage = UIImage(named:"Logo")!
        let imgViewLogo : UIImageView = UIImageView(image: imgLogo)
        imgViewLogo.frame = CGRectMake(20, 2, 60, 60)                

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        let objNavigationController = UINavigationController()

        objNavigationController.navigationBar.addSubview(imgViewLogo)

        let mainView = ViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        objNavigationController.viewControllers = [mainView]
        self.window!.rootViewController = objNavigationController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put it inside an UIImageView

```
let logo = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```